# NullPointerException when clicking ListView item

Tags: java, android

I have a `ListView` with set `onItemClickListener`:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // not important
    if (!found) {
        activity.addSelectedIngredient(ingred);
        parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff99FE80"));
    } else {
        activity.removeSelectedIngredient(ingred);
        parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

The `NullPointerException` is thrown when parent hasn't got child on selected position (e.g. 15). Why? How it's possible that the element might not be present if she already selected it?

Edit:

```
if (!found) {
    activity.addSelectedIngredient(ingred);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff99FE80"));
} else {
    activity.removeSelectedIngredient(ingred);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Comment: What is `found`? Is that reporting false when it shouldn't be? Also, as much as witty titles are fun, they are misleading and unhelpful

Comment: `found` is `true` when the selected item was already clicked and I have to change it's background back to white. Sorry for the title, but I couldn't resist to publish it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getChildAt returns listView's child. getChildAt position is not same position as in your adapter. You can have 1000 items in your adapter and only several childViews in listview because views are reusing.

I think you should change

```
parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

to

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: Thanks :) Could you please also explain me why when I select e.g. the first item then the 11-th's background color also changes?

Comment: after scrolling? 11th item reuses first's item view. show us your new code.

Comment: Yes, after scrolling. Is there any way to change the background color of only one item?

Comment: nope. You should store each item's color somewhere, for example, in item's property, e.g. ingred.color = white. And every time when you fill view with data set view.background=ingred.color.

Comment: Hmm... that's not very convenient but if there's no other way I have no choice. Thanks for explanations :)

Comment: you can create a separate array to save items colors, so you dont have to change your item's class. If only one item selectable at a time you can store it's position, dont need to remember all other item's colors.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
if (!found) {
    activity.addSelectedIngredient(ingred);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff99FE80"));
} else {
    activity.removeSelectedIngredient(ingred);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Explanation:
 so what is happening is that the parent has that view but the indexing is reset. So you clearly don't has any idea as which index is assigned to your element, It depends on the cash the listview has cashed elements for. So instead of getting child you should use the view. This is exactly the same as the item you just clicked.